ADC read with NUCLEO-C031C6 Kit
When ı try to read ADC values with this MCU, ıt does not give me 0 adc value when ı make ground a channel pin. It gives me 120 ADC (/4095) and ı did not get the reason.

Did you calibrate the ADC? Using e.g. HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start() ?

Yes, ı have tried it. It measured ground as 2-3

Ok. That sounds pretty good then. The ADC will always give you an approximation, never an absolutely accurate value. The datasheet will give you the accuracy. And I doubt all "grounds" on your board are at the exact same potential. All signal traces have capacitance and resistance. Update your question with your new information, if you still have a question. But 2 / 4096 seems very acceptable to me.
